# Ajax Autocomplete field: display one value, but use another?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, autocomplete

I've got an autocompleter in a CakePHP app that provides a dropdown list of neighborhoods to attach to a place. I'm pulling from a table 'neighborhoods' with name and id fields. I want the user to see the name of the neighborhood, and I want the app to see the id of the neighborhood and insert it into the places table. How can I make this happen?

Comment: What autocomplete implementation are you using? You just need to return 2 pieces of data (name/id) with Cake and apply the ID to a hidden field on select of the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be to storing the id. Then when a user presses submit you replace the input field's value with your stored value.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking but I don't know how to implement it. Similar to the above hidden input suggestion. Would there be a way to, say, make the id for each <li> be the neighborhood_id, then pull that out and use it in the places db? Kind of like a rigged <select> dropdown? I should mention at this point that my Ajax skills are beginner-level at best...

Comment: Do you have jQuery? You could run .data('id', neighborhood_id) on each.

Answer (score 0):

assign the correct (hidden) value to a hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality is normally achieved with a combobox, which is like an autocomplete, with an underlying `select` elememt, see [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)

Comment: That's kind of how I started to tackle this problem, but I also want the ability to, if the neighborhood doesn't already exist in the database, add it. I guess it might be possible to put an "Add New Neighborhood..." bit of business in the dropdown but I feel like that might be a little harder for the user to discover.